# Quickly add tags in Flickr

Tags: flickr

Is there a faster way to tag photos in Flickr, one at a time, besides pressing "tag" and typing then pressing the "next" link?

Answer (score 5):

of course there is a faster way:

- Go to the `Organize & Create` menu at the top
- Select the pictures you want
- Drag them to the middle of the screen to create a batch
- You can then do a lot of things to this batch, adding tags for example with the `Add tags` button.